# ANTLR: Multiple Inputs

Tags: java, file, input, antlr, grammar

I am trying to use ANTLR for attribute grammar. This is my driver code:

```
import org.antlr.runtime.ANTLRStringStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRFileStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRInputStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;

@SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation", "unused" })
public class mymain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRFileStream("/home/vkmanojk/eclipse-workspace/17040/src/input");
            statementLexer lexer = new statementLexer(input);
            CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
            statementParser parser = new statementParser(tokens);
            System.out.println(parser.expression());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

This program works only for a single input in the *input* file. How do I change the main function so that it works for multiple inputs within the *input* file ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input file contains multiple `expression`s, simply add a parser rule that matches 1 or more `expression`s:

```
expressions
 : expression ( DELIMITER expression )*
 ;

// Your existing expression rule
expression
 : ...
 ;

DELIMITER
 : '\r'? '\n'
 ;
```

If your expressions are delimited by something else than line breaks, change `DELIMITER` accordingly, of course.